# Python keeps ouputting "none"

Tags: python, boolean, python-2.7, palindrome

Whenever I try to run this code:

```
def isPalindrome( theSubList ):
    theSubListtest = theSubList[0:]
    if len(theSubListtest) <= 1:
        return True
    elif len(theSubListtest) == 2:
        x = theSubListtest[0]
        y = theSubListtest[1]
        if (x == y):
            return True
        else:
            return Falsefirst == theSubListtest.pop(0)
    elif len(theSubListtest) > 2:
        first = theSubListtest.pop(0)
        last = theSubListtest.pop()
        if first == last:
            isPalindrome(theSubListtest)
        else:
            return False

candidatePs = [ 
    [1,], 
    range(8), 
    range(4) + range(3,-1,-1), 
    range(4) + [0] + range(3,-1,-1),
    range(3) + range(4) + [0] + range(3,-1,-1),
]

for p in candidatePs :
    print p, isPalindrome( p )
```

it runs correctly for the first two values of p but then ouputs "None" for the following three values. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `def isPalindrome(x): return x == x[::-1]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whoops.

```
if (first == last):
    return isPalindrome(theSubListtest)
else:
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a return. Change these lines:

```
if (first == last):
    isPalindrome(theSubListtest)
```

to

```
if (first == last):
    return isPalindrome(theSubListtest)
```

and the code will work as expected.